# R Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I'm trying to use neuralnet command in R, but i keep getting this error:
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) :
undefined columns selected

I tried specifying columns to see if it's the matter of accessibility (pm$category etc), but it keeps giving me the same error. It shouldn't be necessary as the dataset is already attached, but I'm not sure what else could be the reason.
This is my code:

```
pm <- read.csv("FILENAME")
attach(pm)

trainset <- X[1:640, ]
testset <- X[641:800, ]

#Neural Network
library(neuralnet)

nn <- neuralnet(category~camera+location+photographer, data=trainset, hidden=c(2,1), linear.output=FALSE, threshold=0.01)
nn$result.matrix
```

Comment: Sorry, not following you. You define a `data.frame` `pm` but then you subset `X`. What is `X`?

Comment: I presumed you misstyped `X` for `pm`...? What is the output of `colnames(pm)`? It would help if you could show part of the data you are dealing with, e.g. via `head(pm)`.

Answer (score 0):

**`"undefined columns selected"` error in `neuralnet()` is usually related to invalid column names.**

`neuralnet` won't allow most special characters in the column names, particularly including `" "`, and `","`. Note that `","` is acceptable in the column names of `data.frame` and `data.table`, so it can be confusing when it comes to `neuralnet`.

You can use the function `make.names()` from base package to transform your column names into syntactically valid ones like below:

> `names(pm)=make.names(names(pm))`